# Kotlin program results in error when using blockhound

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, error-handling, blockhound

I have a sceanrio wherein the code is as such:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import reactor.blockhound.BlockHound
    BlockHound.install()
    val throwable: Throwable = assertThrows {
        runBlocking {
            // Calling some method
            }
        }
```

This code fails in some scenarios with message: reactor.blockhound.BlockingOperationError: Blocking call! jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe#park

Can anyone please help me resolve this?